# Why are 2nd seasons sometimes listed as 2nd series?

Tags: anime-production

When I say 'series' I mean in the American not British sense. [Like the British series Hustle has 8 'series' instead of 8 'seasons'.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hustle_(TV_series)#Series_overview) So not that kind of series.

On Wikipedia:

[Kuroko no Basuke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Kuroko%27s_Basketball_episodes) and [Takagi-san](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Teasing_Master_Takagi-san_episodes) each have 1 anime adaptation consisting of 3 seasons (excluding movies). You can see that's how they're listed in the sidebars of their resp original pages: [Kuroko](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuroko%27s_Basketball) and [Takagi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teasing_Master_Takagi-san).

[image]

[The Quintessential Quintuplets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Quintessential_Quintuplets) and [Kaguya-sama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaguya-sama:_Love_Is_War) each have more than 1 anime adaptation. TQQ has Gotoubun no Hanayome and then 'Gotoubun no Hanayome ∬'. Kaguya-sama: Love is War, Kaguya-sama: Love Is War? and 'Kaguya-sama: Love Is War – Ultra Romantic'. In the main Wikipedia pages they are listed in sidebars as like separate adaptations.

[image]

So eg 'Gotoubun no Hanayome ∬' looks not really like a '2nd season' but more like a sequel series. I don't mean parallel spin-offs like [Once Upon a Time in Wonderland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Once_Upon_a_Time_in_Wonderland) or sequel spin-offs like [Yu-Gi-Oh! GX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yu-Gi-Oh!_GX). I mean something like idk maybe [revival](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/110320/whats-the-term-for-some-sequel-where-we-see-the-characters-in-the-original-but) seasons like [Heroes Reborn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heroes_Reborn_(miniseries)) that's treated as a sequel series instead of 5th season. What's going on?

Comment: Personally this seems like more of a Wikipedia presentation question than an anime question, because the titles of the anime aren't indicating any difference. Even the main body of the Wikipedia page treats them as seasons. I don't see any fixed differences that would explain your examples though.

Comment: @TheGamer007 not just wikipedia. also MAL. or even like promotional posters or ads. they don't say it's a new season. they say it's like a sequel series. But anyway I don't see something like this for western series whether live or animated. But for anime it sometimes is or isn't like this. What's up with that?

Comment: The Japanese Wikipedia shows a different categorization: [*Kaguya-sama*](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%8B%E3%81%90%E3%82%84%E6%A7%98%E3%81%AF%E5%91%8A%E3%82%89%E3%81%9B%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84%E3%80%9C%E5%A4%A9%E6%89%8D%E3%81%9F%E3%81%A1%E3%81%AE%E6%81%8B%E6%84%9B%E9%A0%AD%E8%84%B3%E6%88%A6%E3%80%9C) is considered as 1 series with 3 seasons, but [*5-toubun*](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%BA%94%E7%AD%89%E5%88%86%E3%81%AE%E8%8A%B1%E5%AB%81) is considered as 2 separate series, so looks like it depends on their policy for categorization.